# syncing mobile app with web - Flash Builder for PHP

Tags: php, flash, mobile, builder

Im starting experiment with **Flash Builder for PHP** mobile projects and I found it facinating. I could connect the app to a local database, but I was wondering how can I update the data of the mobile app from a website?.
If someone can give me a clue I will really apreciated it.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an API in php. I would create a JSON api:

```
$arr=array($all, $the, $data, $to, $send);
echo json_encode((object)$arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I will give it a try when I finish with some other projects. I made a quick search about JSON and seems to be what I need. I already made conections with the twitter JSON api.